# How to hide parent in deeply nested react router object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I wonder if there is a better way of hiding/not rendering parent content in react router object. I could solve it by conditional rendering, but I am not sure it is the best approach. I have parent, child and grandchild and I will render only grandchild content, but keep the nested structure(for useMatches and other things). I tried with `Outlet` but it didn't help. How can I hide parent and child from DOM?

```
const router: RouteObject = {
  id: "parent",
  path: "parent",
  element: <div><p>Parent</p></div>,
  children: [
    {
      id: "child",
      path: "/parent/child",
      element: <div><p>Child</p></div>,
      children: [
        {
          id: "grandchildLayout",
          index: true,
          element: <div><Outlet /></div>,
        },
        {
          id: "grandchild",
          path: "/parent/child/grandchild",
          element: <div><p>Grandchild</p></div>,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render `Parent` and `Child` as index routes so that they are only rendered on `"/parent"` and `"/parent/child"` exactly each. The parent route of each will render an `Outlet` by default, or you can render a layout route component and `Outlet` of your own if you do actually have some shared UI between the routes.

Example:

```
const router: RouteObject = {
  id: "parent",
  path: "parent",
  children: [
    {
      index: true,
      element: <div><p>Parent</p></div>
    },
    {
      id: "child",
      path: "/parent/child",
      children: [
        {
          index: true,
          element: <div><p>Child</p></div>
        },
        {
          id: "grandchildLayout",
          element: (
            <div>
              <h3>Grandchild Layout</h3>
              <Outlet />
            </div>
          ),
          children: [
            {
              id: "grandchild",
              path: "/parent/child/grandchild",
              element: <div><p>Grandchild</p></div>
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

[image]
[image]
[image]